# Need help resolving Fancybox display issue in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fancybox

Need help resolving a display problem on Fancybox content in IE8. It
works fine in IE7, but when you click on the link in IE8 the content
displays but without any of the styling.

Link: http://www.gotoadvantage.com - click on sub navigation in the
box to the right - where it says advantage overview.

I inherited this from another developer that skipped out, so would
appreciate some quick help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the jQuery Block UI plug-in, not Fancybox. Apparently, ["setExpression" causes IE8 to flip out](http://www.nabble.com/setExpression-makes-IE8-crash-in-blockUI-plugin-td22071588s27240.html). However, it looks like the [newest version of jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#download) fixes this problem.

Comment: Solved the problem completely! Thank you for taking the time to respond. I really appreciate it.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> this is not forcing to load IE7 mode.